# Output all gpo where name like blabla to a file

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

I'm trying to create a script and a part of it should go to the domain, get all the GPO which names start with "MSAVS-" output that to a file and then in some other part of the script read it. problem is, when i do this code:

```
Get-Gpo - all | Where-Object {$._DisplayName - like "MSAVS-*"} | Select-Object 
DisplayName | Output-File test.txt
```

I get the result like this:

blank line

DisplayName

"-----------"

blank line

MSAVS-blabla1

MSAVS-blabla2

MSAVS-blabla3

etc..

I dont want any blank lines, DisplayName and ------- lines
I want to get only the names of the GPOs

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty <String>` for this:

```
Get-Gpo -All | Where-Object { $._DisplayName -like "MSAVS-*" } | Select-Object -ExpandPoperty "DisplayName" | Output-File test.txt
```

`-ExpandProperty` - Specifies a property to select, and indicates that an attempt should be made to expand that property:

- If the specified property is an array, each value of the array is included in the output.
- If the specified property is an object, the objects properties are expanded for every InputObjec

Comment: I did though i have 15 or less reputation :o thats why i guess its not showing

Answer (score 0):

Get-Gpo -All | Where-Object { $._DisplayName -like "MSAVS-*" } | Select-Object -ExpandPoperty "DisplayName" | Output-File test.txt

FYI:
$_.DisplayName